# In react 18.0, why asynchronous useLayoutEffect's callback and asynchronous useEffect's callback cannot cause UI flickering during 'First Paint'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect, flicker

I am new in React.js and cannot completely understand the source code.

As I can see in the source code of **react 18.0**, my function defined in **useLayoutEffect** or **useEffect** is called by MessageChannel API's postMessage **asynchronously** during **'First Paint'**.

[useLayoutEffect breakpoint screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OroFS.jpg)

[useEffect breakpoint screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHOzF.png)

But, why DOM changes writen in my function (either in useLayoutEffect or useEffect) cannot cause UI flickering during 'First Paint' according to the performance tab in Chrome browser's dev tools.

[frame timing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfpu1.jpg)

Header/index.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import logoUrl from "./logo.png";
import style from "../../../index.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import { randomFruit, pick } from "./pickRandomFruitCreator";

export default function Header() {
  const [fruit, setFruit] = useState(randomFruit);
  const text = `change fruit to: ${fruit}`;
  const obj = {
    some: {
      text,
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const ele = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    ele.textContent =  'useEffect'
    console.log("useEffect finished");
  }, [obj]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // const ele = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    // ele.textContent = "uselayoutEffect";
    console.log("useLayoutEffect finished");
  }, [obj]);

  const onchange = () => {
    pick();
    setFruit(randomFruit);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <img src={logoUrl} />
      <button className={style.changeState} onClick={onchange}>
        {text}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Header/pickRandomFruitCreator.js

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
let pickerIndex = 0;
let randomFruit = fruits[pickerIndex];

const pick = () => {
  pickerIndex = pickerIndex + 1;
  if (pickerIndex > fruits.length - 1) {
    pickerIndex = 0;
  }
  randomFruit = fruits[pickerIndex]
}


export { pick, randomFruit }
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want to get flickering?

Comment: @user4980215 Yes, I expect to get flickering, but in fact I can't, This is weird.